# Make order notes field required for variations with specific product attribute term in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I have few variable products with variation that have `pa_size` and `pa_color` attributes *(taxonomy)*. I have 4 sizes ("s", "m", "l" and "special") and 4 colors.

My problem is, for the "special" size: Customer must fill order notes in checkout page, but since it is not a required field, they easily miss it.

I found some code for product categories that I have changed to handle `pa_size` taxonomy. With this code I was thinking to make order notes checkout field required for purchased product variations with `pa_size` attribute.

Here is my code:

```
function conditional_variation( $variations ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( has_term( $variations, 'pa_size', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'make_order_notes_required_field' );
function make_order_notes_required_field( $fields ) {
    $variations = array("pa_size");

    if ( conditional_variation( $variations ) ) {
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

But I can't make it work.

I Tried many ways but I cant find a way to make it required for only "special" size attribute term. What I mean is if any variation combination or single product in cart contains "special" attribute (black-special, blue-special only "special" etc.) field must be required, otherwise (small-blue , red-large only red etc.) it must be optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead *(Be sure that **"Special"** is the right **term name** for `pa_size` taxonomy set on the related variations of your variable product(s))*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'make_order_notes_required_field' );
function make_order_notes_required_field( $fields ) {
    $taxonomy  = 'pa_size';
    $term_name = 'Special';

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_attribute($taxonomy) === $term_name ) {
            $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.